# ElasticSearch to Django APIView - Django stripping important data

Tags: django, elasticsearch, python-requests

I'm trying to proxy my ElasticSearch connection via Django.

I want the django URL to behave exactly as connecting directly to Elastic Search (:9200).

However, every time the Django URL makes "_search" request, the part of the ES response has been **REMOVED**

Django gives me "Hits" directly- not the **other** important data (eg 'took', 'timed out', 'shards' etc)

I have compared the identical calls (ie sending the same params) of DJANGO and ES direct here- [link][1].

How do I stop django filtering/blocking that data?

## services.py

```
def elastic_result(id, request):
    url = 'http://localhost:9200/_search' 
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_search', params=request.data)
    items = r.json()
    return Response(items)
```

## views.py

```
from services import elastic_result

class ElasticView(APIView):
    permission_classes=[]
    def post(self, request):
        item_list = elastic_result(id, request)
        return item_list
        pass
```

## url

```
router.register(r'elastic/_search', ElasticView, base_name='Elastic')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah very simple, my parameters were not arriving!

```
def elastic_result(id, request):
    url = 'http://localhost:9200/_search' 
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/_search', params=request.data)
    items = r.json()
    return Response(items)
```

I just needed to change `params=request.data` to `json=request.data` and voila :)

Answer (score 0):

**I have added `payload = {'q': pa + '*'}`** I works fine for me I could proxy the proxy my ElasticSearch connection via Django. Moreover, by adding RegExp '*' gives the **Repeat the preceding character zero or more times. For example:

ab*     # matches 'a', 'ab', 'abb', 'abbb', etc.**

```
import json
import requests
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ElasticView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        url = 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_search'
        pa = request.GET.get('q')
        payload = {'q': pa + '*'}
        r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
        items = r.json()
        return Response(items)
```